# Python Can't extract table from html with Pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, xml

I'm trying to get a table from this [url](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/dayAheadPrices/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.01.2020+00:00%7CCET%7CDAY&biddingZone.values=CTY%7C10YLT-1001A0008Q!BZN%7C10YLT-1001A0008Q&resolution.values=PT60M&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)#)

So this url returns prices at a specific date, but I need to get prices from the whole year, which is possible by pressing exportdata --> Day-ahead Prices [12.1.D] (Year, XML)

I checked the buttons attributes which were dataitem="DAY_AHEAD_PRICES" timerange="YEAR" exporttype="XML">Day-ahead Prices [12.1.D] (Year, XML)

And tried using them

```
def extract_from_url():

    table = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"timerange": "YEAR", "dataitem": "DAY_AHEAD_PRICES", "exporttype": "XML"})

    return table
```

It returns no tables were found, but if I were to remove those attributes it would return prices of the specific date fine.
[here is the html of the webpage and specific table I need]

[image: 1]